# Is it possible for an issue to appear only in one GitLab issue board?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

I have made two boards for issues on GitLab, for two different teams. Is it possible, when creating a new issue, to make it appear just on one of the boards?

Setting up the boards so far:

1. I created three different issue labels for different states of issues (worked on, review, blocked)
2. I created two boards, with both `Show the Open list` and `Show the Closed list` options enabled for both of the boards.

Editing the boards only allows me to change the name or change the open/closed list options.

Comment: Yes? It really depends on how you've set up the boards. Your question can't be answered without more details on how the boards were set up.

Comment: @Arty-chan I added the information to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two teams use two disjoint sets of labels and you are ok with hiding the "Open" and "Closed" lists, you can hide those two lists and use only the labels for one team in its board and only the labels for the other team in its board.

Otherwise you can filter which issues end up in any of your boards by editing the scope of that board. Board scope, however, is a feature available only with Gitlab Premium. It is ([documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issue_board.html#configurable-issue-boards)).

Comment: This does solve my problem, even though it is not very convenient